# problems sending Firebase message with data

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, pyfcm

I am able to successfully send a title/text message using pyfcm:

```
result = push_service.notify_multiple_devices(registration_ids=registration_tokens, message_title="title",
                                                  message_body="testing")
```

But when I try to send a data message, it fails:

```
    payload = {
        'action': 'testing',
        'test number': 1,
        'question': "what do you do with a klondike bar?",
    }
    result = push_service.multiple_devices_data_message(registration_ids=registration_tokens, data_message=payload)
```

In the first case, I receive the text/message in my FirebaseMessagingService on the phone in the onMessageReceived method as expected.  In the second case (dictionary data payload), it is never received:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    RemoteMessage.Notification data = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    System.out.print("here");
}
```

In both cases, result seems to be a success.

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: Could you print the actual value of the `payload` in the second case?

Comment: payload = {
        'action': 'testing',
        'test number': 1,
        'question': "what do you do with a klondike bar?",
    }

Comment: Err... Shouldn't that payload items be enclosed in either a `notification` or `data` parent?

Comment: I'm following the directions at https://pypi.org/project/pyfcm/.  There is no mention of either a notification or data parent.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with `multiple_devices_data_message`

I tried this:

`result = push_service.single_device_data_message(registration_id=registration_tokens[0], data_message=payload)`

and it worked as expected.  So to solve my problem for now, I will need to iterate over each registration token, calling `single_device_data_message` for each one